# javascript: get un-destructed parameter in function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I need to get the un-destructed parameters inside a function. What would be the best way?

```
const foo = ({url, options, header, body, auth = 1}) => {
    //...do things with the parameters...
    let params = {url, options, header, body, auth}; // Is there an easy way?
    bar(params);
}
```

Comment: const foo = params => { }; don't destructure if you need undestructered???

Comment: But then I lost the convenience of parameter destructing. I need both :)

Comment: That's not possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 destructuring function parameter - naming root object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051011/es6-destructuring-function-parameter-naming-root-object)

Comment: @Xufox Thanks, that's actually a good approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a single parameter in `foo` and do the destructuring inside it. Then, you would do some stuff with `url`, `options`, `header`, `body` and `auth` and finally call `bar` like `bar({ ...args, auth })`, [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `args` and adding `auth` as well:

```js
const bar = (baz) => {
  console.log(baz);
};

const foo = (args) => {
  const { url, options, header, body, auth = 1 } = args;

  // Do stuff with url, options, header, body and auth...

  bar({ ...args, auth });
};

foo({ url: 'www.google.com', options: {}, header: {}, body: 'Hi there!' });
foo({ url: 'www.google.com', options: {}, header: {}, body: 'Hi there!', auth: false });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100vh !important;
}
```