# Access destructured parameter by name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What I need: a way of accessing a destructured (or spread?) parameter by name.

My code is as follows:

```
open = ({ title = "Confirm", subTitle, link = {} } = {}) => {
    this.setState({ isVisible: true, ...params?? });
}
```

So basically I'm receiving a single object with properties `a,b,c` having  default values for properties `a,c`.

After this, I want to spread the received object into my state (or for any other purpose). But.. I don't know **what** to spread..

So let's assume I'm trying to call it `params` as in the example.

What I tried:

`open = (params : { title = "Confirm", subTitle, link = {} } = {}) => {`

**`^ Unexpected token error`**

---

`open = ({ title = "Confirm", subTitle, link = {} } = {} : params) => {`

**`^ , expected`**

---

`this.setState({ isVisible: true, ...arguments });` 
(attempt to access ES5 `arguments` object)

**`^'arguments' is not allowed in class field initializer' error`**

---

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: Are you asking how to name the whole argument **and** destructure it, simultaneously, in the parameter definition? If so: you can't do that, just move the destructuring *inside* the function, and it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29051011/3001761.

Comment: Don't spread then in the argument list, but inside the function spread it?

Comment: Why not just *not* use the spread in the function formal parameter list? Then you'll have a named reference to the entire original object, and you can then spread to your heart's content into local variables or whatever.

Comment: I have the same issue. Was hoping one day we'd have: `({ title, sub, link } = source ) => { ... }` or similar, but atm, you destructure inside the function body.

Comment: Yeah, after doing some more research I agree with you this is not possible since the object was already spread.

Comment: Also @Pointy, how would I handle default values then?

Comment: You can use default values in simple object-to-variable(s) destructuring assignment.

Comment: @Pointy: but they wouldn't be reflected in `namedReference`, is what I think he means.

Comment: Ok but then I'm still not able to spread the received config object into my state.. I would have to write each variable individually.

Answer (score 0):

There is no object you could spread after destructuring. (Well, there's `arguments[0]`, but that's the actual argument not a new object containing the default values of your parameters).

You will want to explicitly use all the variables that you destructured into to form the new object:

```
function open({title = "Confirm", subTitle, link = {}} = {}) {
    this.setState({ isVisible: true, title, subTitle, link });
}
```