# ES6 Destructuring — refer to this/self

Tags: ecmascript-6, syntax

Got a class like this:

```
class Item {
  constructor (next = null) {
    this.next = next
  }

  get self () { return this; }

  *[Symbol.iterator] () {
    yield this;
    if (this.next) yield *this.next;
  }
}
```

What is basically a linked list. Lets assume the list has at least three items and that `root` holds a reference to the head.

Right now, I can iterate like that and have a reference to both, the current item itself and its successor.

```
for (let { self, next } of root) {

}
```

Can the above be done without having the »self getter« withing the class, with destructuring only? So I have tried `for (let {this, next} of root)` but that does not work.

So can I have a reference to the »source object« with destructuring ?

Comment: Does it work without the destructuring?

Comment: yes. but that I need to access the successor like `self.next` all the time.

Comment: An object doesn't have a property that references itself, so there is nothing to destructure. All you could do is split this up into two parts: `for (let self of root) { const {next} = self; }`.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29051011/218196 maybe.

Comment: @FelixKling Already got that…

Comment: I don't think you can, this might be a limitation of destructuring.

Comment: That is why I am asking, so this might be the answer ;)

Comment: Btw, you don't need to call the `[Symbol.iterator]()`, you can just do `if (this.next) yield* this.next;`

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for this one, much better so… ;)