# Destructuring nested objects: How to get parent and its children values?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

The function below receives an object that has a property `current`, which is also an object, and it has `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties.

Here, nested destructuring works as expected with `Start` and `End` variables, But I also need the value for `current`.

```js
function someFunction({ current: { selectionStart: Start, selectionEnd: End } }) {

    // do something with current, Start, and End
}
```

How do I get it using destructuring?

Comment: i understand that i can go to deep levels  of an object by destructuring , but i couldn't find how to get the value of the object it self , not its properties .
so in this particular case , i don't know how to get the value of current .

Comment: You should try to word your question better to clarify that `Start` and `End` are working properly, but `current` is undefined. @adiga has just answered this.

Comment: @caesay , is it clear now ? if it's not please let me know . thank you .

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The first destructuring creates only `Start` and `End` variables. If you want to create `current` as a variable, then you need to declare it again.

```
function ({ current: { selectionStart: Start, selectionEnd: End }, current }, AppStateSetter) {

// do something with current , Start , and End

}
```

You can [test it on the Babel compiler](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBCBGArApsWBeGBvAUDGwArgE7HJhQBc2e-MEyANqlAJbgDKUAhsVTACIADsRBCYARgEAaWvgbM07MAFEwAE2rDRQgEwDaAXxzGcoSLCwESZCtSsKWyrr34u-0-kyfg1mmH4whkEwmAgoaADcQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.2.2):

This code:

```
const object = {
  current: {
    selectionStart: "prop 1",
    selectionEnd: "prop2"
  }
}

const { current: { selectionStart: Start, selectionEnd: End } } = object;
```

Gets trasnpiled to:

```
var object = {
  current: {
    selectionStart: "prop 1",
    selectionEnd: "prop2"
  }
};

var _object$current = object.current,
    Start = _object$current.selectionStart,
    End = _object$current.selectionEnd;
```

As you can see, `current` variable is not created.

Comment: A note to remember, best practise is to spread the remaining props. So if you used `...rest` (name could be anything). You could have accessed current via `rest.current`

Comment: @Neil `rest` won't have `current` [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBA3jYBXATigpmKAueMLoA26wUAluAMpQCGKOM1dUANPkSeeAKJgAmuXnxgBfNgDpJGaKJgBeGDQDcQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=env&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.4.5&externalPlugins=)

Comment: If `...rest` is added after that last property `selectionEnd`. Then this will be the remainder object props. I did not notice the second level destructure.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue you are facing happens when current is `undefined`.

You can try destructing with default value.

```
function ({ current: { selectionStart: Start, selectionEnd: End } = {} }, AppStateSetter) {
  // do something with Start and End
}
```

If you think you need to access `current` as well, try destructuring inside the function.

```
function ({ current = {}}, AppStateSetter) {
  const { selectionStart: Start, selectionEnd: End } = current
  // do something with current, Start and End
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can destructure and assign the default value in a single statement.

```
function someFunction({
        current: {
          selectionStart: Start,
          selectionEnd: End
        } = {},
        current = {}
      },
      AppStateSetter) {
      // now you can use the let variables Start, End and current,
      // with current's default value set to empty object
      }
```

If you don't want to assign default value to current, but still want to use that variable, you can just write the name of the property with no assignment. When *someFunction* is called with empty object, if you don't assign a default value to current it will be undefined.

```
    function someFunction1({
        current: {
          selectionStart: Start,
          selectionEnd: End
        } = {},
        current
      },
      AppStateSetter) {
      // now you can use the let variables Start, End and current
      // if empty object is passed, current will be undefined
    }
```

JsFiddle snippet: [Nested object destructuring with and without default values](https://jsfiddle.net/munnangiP/kp3e70wg/)